# Git merge between 2 branches: is parents order relevant for later merges?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Let's say I have 2 branches: master and feature, where master represents the stable main stream.

Now I want to bring new fixes from master into my feature branch.
In the past we tried to merge from master into feature branch but this workflow caused some problems of changes being reverted later on when integrating the feature branch into master.

Another issue is the history because now when you look to the branch history all commits from master and feature branch will be interleaved, making it impossible to rebase later on (for instance, we would like to perform a final rebase to cleanup and compact the history, by squashing some commits, before integrating it into master).

One option would be to rebase the feature branch onto master every time we want to get fixes from master. But this requires more discipline from developers and the conflict rate is higher since each commit must be merged individually.

So I was wondering if we could, instead, simulating the integration from feature branch into master, but then pushing it to a new feature branch in the remote. This will be a kind of intermediate integration. Development would then proceed from here, without actually changing the remote master. The only difference between this and merging from master into feature branch is the order of the parents in the merge commit. Merging from feature branch into master, would create a merge commit where the last commit from master is the first parent.

May this help Git to perform a cleaner merge afterwards when making the final integration into master? Or is it irrelevant the order of the parents and thus this is exactly the same as merging from master into feature?

Comment: I disagree that the conflict rate is higher when rebasing.  Instead, the friction between two branches is always about the same, but in a rebase the conflicts may play out over many commits, whereas in a merge it happens all at once.  Generally speaking, you should adopt either a merge-based workflow or a rebase-workflow, and don't mix the two.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When I say the conflict rate may be higher, it has to do with the fact that each commit must be merged individually, which means you may need to resolve the conflict in same lines more than once

Comment: Well, you could use `rerere` to avoid resolving the same conflicts.  But even without that, it's clear that rebase would have more conflicts than merge, since some intermediate commit `A` may conflict, but the conflict may not exist in the final tip that's being merged.  In a rebase, you would still have to resolve that conflict just to apply that intermediate commit.